# How to get original image name in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, image-uploading

In codeigniter I want to upload image to URL:

http://example.com/uploads/temp/

when I submit the form I want to get original image name and image maybe named like this when upload success:

http://example.com/uploads/temp/iphone5_2012_09_20_02_02_03.png

image name structure:

[original_name]*[year]*[month]*[day]*[hour]*[minute]*[second]

So how can I get original image name before upload in codeigniter?

Comment: Are you using image upload library of codeigniter

Comment: upload for upload, image_lib for resize and file library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve the file name with:

```
$img_name = $_FILES['your_name_in_the_form']['name'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call upload Library method Data

```
$data = $this->upload->data()
```

that will return file name

```
echo $data['filename'];
```

Comment: My question is get original image name before upload. I accept Christian Giupponi answer.

Comment: with upload library you can do it with this instruction i have put and without upload library you do it with Christian Giupponi. YOu ahave tag of Codeigniter so i thought you might be using it because it is too much easy

Answer (score 0):

`$img_name = $_FILES['file_upload_field_name']['name'];`